# merge multiple CSV files into one database using PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have created a database using (PhpMyAdmin) that include one table (contains 4 columns )
at the moment the database is empty. 
I have 5 CSV files, each one contains around 20 columns. 
I would like to import specified columns (for example, column 1, 2 ,3 and 4 from each of the five CSV files) and merge them into one data base 
in other word, import the first 4 columns of the first csv file and repeat the same procedure for all files, and finally I would like to have one datebase that has 4 columns and several rows

I have tried to do that in using PhpMyAdmin but it shows several errors and the database still empty , doesnt update.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Sooo what are you expecting as an answer?

Comment: @DiarSelimi , I have tried to do that in using PhpMyAdmin but it shows several errors and the database still empty , doesnt update

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's [LOAD DATA Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) can do that.. 
Minimal answer as the question information is also minimal..

The BNF

```
LOAD DATA
    [LOW_PRIORITY | CONCURRENT] [LOCAL]
    INFILE 'file_name'
    [REPLACE | IGNORE]
    INTO TABLE tbl_name
    [PARTITION (partition_name [, partition_name] ...)]
    [CHARACTER SET charset_name]
    [{FIELDS | COLUMNS}
        [TERMINATED BY 'string']
        [[OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY 'char']
        [ESCAPED BY 'char']
    ]
    [LINES
        [STARTING BY 'string']
        [TERMINATED BY 'string']
    ]
    [IGNORE number {LINES | ROWS}]
    [(col_name_or_user_var
        [, col_name_or_user_var] ...)]
    [SET col_name={expr | DEFAULT},
        [, col_name={expr | DEFAULT}] ...]
```

**Query**

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'csv1.csv' INTO TABLE <your_table_name>
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(
    col1
  , col2 
  , col3
  , col4
);
```

col1, col2, col3, col4 in all queries needs to be valid column name of the table where you what to import. 
Also you need to repeat the statement foreach csv file your have..